# Command ACCEPT sql plus

Tags: sql, plsql, sqlplus

I've problem with ACCEPT command in sql plus. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong - all the time got an error which says: "Encountered the symbol ".." when expecting one of the following:"
Anyone?
Thanks in advance.

```
select concat('poid_id: ',poid_id0) from przykladowa3 ;

set serveroutput ON;
declare
begin
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Czy usuwamy? T/N');
end;
/
set scan on;
declare
mark char;
cursor cur is select * from przykladowa3;
rowtype cur%rowtype;
begin
ACCEPT mark char PROMPT 'Enter smth:  '
open cur;
  if (mark='T') THEN
    loop
        fetch cur into rowtype;
        exit when cur%notfound;
        delete from przykladowa3 where poid_id0=rowtype.poid_id0;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Successfully removed: ' || rowtype.poid_id0);
        commit;
    end loop;  
  else 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SOME TEXT');
  end if;
end;
/
```

error:

```
ORA-06550: linia 6, kolumna 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "MARK" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;
```

Comment: Could you please attach the error message?

Comment: hello agent5566. Error message: ORA-06550: linia 6, kolumna 8:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "MARK" when expecting one of the following:
:= . ( @ % ;

Comment: First of all you should set `mark` data type length, for example `char(1)`, also you are mixing pl\sql and sqlplus code. There is no such statement as `ACCEPT` in pl\sql.

Comment: `accept` is a **SQLPlus** command, not a PL/SQL statement. You can't use that in PL/SQL

Comment: Of course, I'm using that command in sql plus. When i'm trying to run my script then that error message occur...

Comment: I set martk data type lenght to char(2), unfortanely it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

ACCEPT is an sqlplus function.  Not a PL/SQL one.  So you can't have it in the pl/sql scope since the interpreter/engine will not accept it.

```
/* sqlplus scope */
set serveroutput on
ACCEPT lastname CHAR FORMAT 'A20' PROMPT 'Enter employee lastname: ';

/*PLSQL engine */
begin
    dbms_output.put_line ('Variable is: &lastname');
end;
/
```

Just move the accept out of pl/SQL scope (plus sqlplus works with sqlplus variables, not pl/sql)

Comment: Hello Olafur, I'm using sqlplus, i run that script from sqlplus line.. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Edit. Ok I Understand :) Thanks a lot Olafur! It works

Comment: Can I put variable from ACCCEPT command into PL/SQL code? For example in if/else statement?

Comment: @maciek2791: you can **not** use `accept` in a PL/SQL block because it is **not** a valid PL/SQL statement.

Comment: @maciek2791: yes, you can refer to the "variable" (it's really a substitution string) in your PL/SQL, just as demonstrated in Olafur's answer (`...'Variable is: &lastname'`).